# Помогите плиз составить SQL запрос

Tags: sql

Помогите, пожалуйста:)

Есть три таблицы:

1. Книги

   ```
   СREATE TABLE Books
   ('book_id' int, 'book_name' varchar(7), 'book_price' int);


   INSERT INTO Books
   ('book_id', 'book_name', 'book_price')
   VALUES
   (3, 'Book3', 100),
   (2, 'Book2', 5),
   (1, 'Book1', 10);
   ```
2. Заказчики

   ```
   CREATE TABLE Customers
   ('customer_id' int, 'customer_name' varchar(10));

   INSERT INTO Customers
   ('customer_id', 'customer_name')
   VALUES  
   (2, 'Petrov'),
   (1, 'Ivanov');
   ```
3. Заказы

   ```
   CREATE TABLE Orders
   ('order_id' int, 'customer_id' int, 'book_id' int, 'count' int);

   INSERT INTO Orders
   ('order_id', 'customer_id', 'book_id', 'count')
   VALUES
   (3, 2, 1, 1),
   (2, 1, 3, 5),
   (1, 1, 2, 1);
   ```

В результате запроса, который надо составить, должна получиться таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE Results
('Name' varchar(10), 'Book' varchar(7), 'Count' int, 'Order_sum' int);

INSERT INTO Orders
('Name', 'Book', 'Count', 'Order_sum')
VALUES
(Ivanov, Book2, 1, 5),
(Ivanov, Book3, 5, 500),
(Petrov,Book1, 1, 10);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 SELECT customer_name, book_name, count, count*book_price
    FROM Orders
      INNER JOIN Customers
              ON Orders.customer_id = Customers.costumer_id
      INNER JOIN Books
              ON Orders.book_id = Books.book_id
    ORDER BY customer_name
```

Comment: Большущее спасибо!